# My iPod Touch won't play some of my files

Tags: itunes, ipod-touch, file

I've been having trouble with my iPod Touch. I mostly use it for listening to podcasts, however not only will some of the files not play, some aren't even accessible. Where files should be, there is simply an icon with a silver musical note on a white background.

Comment: What iPod Touch model and iOS version are you running?

Comment: @RedEagle2000 I have a 64gb iPod Touch with the latest iOS 6.0. I am quite confused,because now my files are playing.

Comment: Wait, um, iOS 8.4 is the latest. Do you mean that you have a 4th Gen running iOS 6?

Comment: @RedEagle2000 I'm not sure about the generation but  yeah a 64G iPod Touch. Whether there was an error or if it was my fault for properly using it. What do know is that some of the music icons had not been responding consistently or at all.  And some of my music files were either not visible or accessible. Everything is working now,but I'd like to know what was wrong.

Comment: Like I said in my answer, it sounds like just a software bug. Can you update it any further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's working now, it sounds like a software bug. I'd go ahead and update it iOS 6.1.6, the latest version that the 4th Gen iPod Touch supports.